# Trying to Import Image in Python Using OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

I am a beginner and was trying to follow along with an online tutorial but got stopped a minute in trying to import an image.

I am trying to import a picture using the following code:

```py
import cv2

picture = cv2.imread(r"‪C:\Users\spenc\Desktop\IMG_4666.JPEG")

cv2.imshow("Output" ,picture)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, I receive the error:

```
TypeError: "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable."
```

I have tried with multiple images as well of different file types.

[image: Picture of file path]

Comment: Plz write whole code in which numpy.ndarray is written.

Comment: @MafazAhsan `picture` is the `numpy.ndarray`. It is returned by  `cv2.imread`

Comment: Try to convert your image in a jpg or png image, if you are in windows platform you can use paint to do it

Comment: @Diroallu unfortunately no luck :/

Comment: Which version of OpenCV, Python do you use? The code example above looks fine, I can't reproduce your error. I'd suspect problems with installation, maybe you lack some packages or versions are incompatible. Could you show the full call stack?

Comment: Try to print your numpy.ndarray object in python console and show us the result, if it's "None" there is a problem with the path of image

Comment: @Diroallu I tried that out and I got "None". Thank you so much for your help. Now to figure out why it isn't a valid path.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a new project and moving the photo into that project directory. My code now looks like:                                                             import cv2
picture = cv2.imread("IMG_4666.JPEG")
cv2.imshow("Output" ,picture)
cv2.waitKey(0)